# TexMaker not compiling a new pdf (pdflatex + view pdf)

Tags: pdftex, texmaker

I have Texmaker installed on my laptop and desktop, both 5.03 (I originally installed them at the same time) and while my desktop works fine my laptop's version refuses to compile a new pdf file or update the embedded viewer. I'm opening and editing the same files on each via google drive back up and sync, but not at the same time. When I originally installed it it was working fine but stopped without me changing anything (to my knowledge).

I have tried reinstalling TexMaker and I have looked through the configuration but, from old solutions it seems all right. I have attached images of my configure options.

Any help would be much appreciated!

[image: My settings]

Comment: Write to the author for support. Debugging applications is quite difficult with only a screenshot and no info about e.g. error messages.

Comment: There are no error messages at all. How do I write to the author?

Comment: Search for a contact address in the help or on the website.

Comment: First check if you copy files to a simple local directory such as c:\myfiles does it work if so then it can be some rights issue with the drive. are both laptop and desktop using same protocols (wireless or ethernet) are you the same user level and user name and system pathname on both machines?